# Remove limits on parse server after migration

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I've migrated my parse app on a IBM Bluemix hosting using this node js app https://github.com/ukmadlz/parse-on-bluemix
Despite the parse server is now installed only on my hosting environment I'm trying to remove the very annoying limit of 30 requests per sec.

Does anybody know how to that? I've tried looking into parse server source code but I couldn't spot it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's was already removed in parse server open source.

Comment: This makes sense but then why I still get errors because my cron job is exceeding the limits?
If I open the parse dashboard it says that the migration is complete, am I missing something?

Comment: When your app is still running in Parse.com even after migration this limit is activated. Your app need to be completly out of parse.com to work without limits.

Comment: By "Your app need to be completly out of parse.com to work without limits" do you mean I should delete the app in the Parse.com dashboard?

Comment: Please only delete your app in Parse.com if you are sure that all requests are being made to your own parse server. For now if your app making requests in both your parse server and parse.com don't delete it yet.

When you will be fully retired in parse.com then 30/s will be automaticaly removed. 

Hope this helps.